# Array only printing one number

Tags: asp.net, arrays

I am having trouble printing my array in a asp:Label. the array is 5 numbers long, but it will only print out one of the numbers when I do the id.Text = arrayname;

Here is the method:

```
void random4helper()
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    int min = 1;
    int max = 51;
    int randomNum;
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    bool loop = true;

    while (loop)
    {
        randomNum = rand.Next(min, max);

        if (!meganumbers4.Contains(randomNum))
        {
            meganumbers4[i] = randomNum;
            count += 1;
            i += 1;
        }

        if (count == 5)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }


    for (int j = 0; j < meganumbers4.Length; j++)
    {
        d.Text = meganumbers4[j] + " ";
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding Label:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="a" CssClass="print" Text="A"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value in each loop. Instead, you need to add the new value to the current value. Change this line:

```
d.Text = meganumbers4[j] + " ";
```

To:

```
d.Text += meganumbers4[j] + " ";
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `d.Text = ""` before `for` loop, in case sub is called again.